# controller nto getting the return value of factory

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

my controller gets {"$$state": {"status" :0 } } from the factory instead of the value that's supposed to be passed by the factory. how do i get the value from the factory?

here is my controller.js code:

```
.controller('omnipayLoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'userFactory', function ($scope, $stateParams, $location, userFactory) {
$scope.userdata = {}
$scope.enterlogin = function(usern,pass) {
   alert('get = '+ JSON.stringify(userFactory.getUser(usern)) );
}
}])
```

here is my services.js code:

```
.factory('userFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
var users = [];

return {
    getUser: function(uname){
         return $http.get("http://10.10.9.169/UserService/api/users/" + uname).then(function(response){
           if(response.data == null)
           {
               users = null;
           }
           else
           {
               users = response.data;
           }
           return users;
         });
        }

};
}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to catch the promise in the controller instead of the factory.

```
  .factory('userFactory', ['$http', function($http) {
        var users = [];
        return {
            getUser: function(uname) {
                return $http.get("http://10.10.9.169/UserService/api/users/" + uname)
            }
        };
    }])
    .controller('omnipayLoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'userFactory', function($scope, $stateParams, $location, userFactory) {
        $scope.userdata = {}
        $scope.enterlogin = function(usern, pass) {
            userFactory.getUser(usern).then(function(response) {
                alert('get = ' + JSON.stringify(response.data));
            })
        }
    }])
```

Comment: @Sydnie S no prob. Cheers